# The server has rejected the client credentials, duplex wcf service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, windows-services, networkcredentials

I host a wcf service with tcp binding on a windows service. It works correctly on our LAN, however when the users wanna connect to the service from internet, they get the following error:

> The server has rejected the client credentials

this is my service config:

```
 service behaviorConfiguration="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1Behavior"
        name="LivePushServiceLib.SubscribeService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WCF_Interface.ISubscribeService">

        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://188.x.x.x:8524/SubscribeService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using default security with NetTcpBinding which is Windows. In your LAN I assume everyone is using Windows credentials quite happily. However, people from the Internet are unlikely to have credentials on your domain

If you want to use this across the Internet look at setting security to something like TransportWithMessageCredential and then use a credential type of username. This allows Internet based clients to authenticate with a user name which you can validate in a custom UsernamePasswordValidator